# Python namedlist FACTORY default with values

Tags: python, python-2.7, namedtuple

The [namedlist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/namedlist) package in Python is similar to collections.namedtuple and allows for mutable instances.

Declaring mutable default values requires the use of `FACTORY`, ex:

```
from namedlist import namedlist, FACTORY
A = namedlist('A', [('x', FACTORY(list))])
```

I now need to that list to have defaults, but the code below doesn't work:

```
A = namedlist('A', [('x', FACTORY(list([1, 2])))])
```

The code below creates a list with defaults, but every instance of `A` will point to the same object, which is the reason we need factories in the first place:

```
A = namedlist('A', [('x', [1, 2])])
```

How do I create a `namedlist` field with a factory with values?

Comment: I've never heard of namedlist so I don't understand the use case. Why is this preferable to an object or dict?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist to me, the benefits of namedlist over namedtuple is that it's mutable. The benefits for the project I'm working on (not in general) are: less verbose declarations than classes, use of the IDE's intellisense which dicts don't have, supports default values, which dicts don't have also.

Comment: Dicts definitely support default values, in several ways. `setdefault`, `get`, `pop`, also there is `collections.defaultdict`. "Less verbose declarations than classes" -- not really. They're backed by a class declaration in a 3rd party lib that's just not in your source. You're declaring them by instantiating a class which is of equal verbosity to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a function to `FACTORY` that creates a new object when called.

```py
A = namedlist('A', [('x', FACTORY(lambda: [1, 2]))])
```

Comment: Please explain your code, otherwise OP or other future readers might be confused

Comment: Wow, had completely forgotten about this question.. (almost 5 years ago).  Python has since come out with dataclasses, that do what namedlist does and more.